# Python extend array module and optimize

Tags: arrays, optimization, python-2.7, types, long-integer

I have started to write a module for typed arrays in Python27. So far, so good; but I have come to a halt. I have noticed that the Long type in python is only 4 bytes, but it should be 8 bytes on a 64-bit processor. Can I specify that?

Is there any way to clean up my `__new__(self)` method? I have tried to override the super constructor: `__init__(self, typecode[, initializer])`, but I does not let me alter the parameters.

For example, the following code does not work:

```
class TypedIntegerArray(array):
    def __init__(self, type, size):
        array.__init__(self, type, (0 for i in range(0,size)))
```

I would like to run a `setup()` method on the array, to place all the logic in `__new__(self)`, but `__new__()` happens before the object is created, so I have to create a temp object to grab the properties from it before I return it.

**Module**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Typecode       Type        Min bytes
#    'c'        character         1
#    'b'     signed integer       1
#    'B'    unsigned integer      1
#    'h'     signed integer       2
#    'H'    unsigned integer      2
#    'i'     signed integer       2
#    'I'    unsigned integer      2
#    'l'     signed integer       4
#    'L'    unsigned integer      4
#    'f'     floating point       4
#    'd'     floating point       8

from array import array
from math import floor, log10
from sys import getsizeof, maxsize

class TypedIntegerArray(array):
    def __new__(self, type, size):
        arr = array.__new__(self, type, (0 for i in range(0,size)))
        exp = 1 if arr.typecode.islower() else 0
        self.mask = int('FF'*arr.itemsize, 16)
        self.frmt = '{0:0' + str(arr.itemsize * 8) + 'b}'
        self._maxValue = 2 ** (arr.numBits() - exp) - 1
        self._minValue = -1 * (self._maxValue + 1) if exp == 1 else 0
        return arr
    def size(self):
        return len(self)
    def numBits(self):
        return self.itemsize * 8
    def intToBin(self, value):
        value = (value + self.mask) + 1 if value < 0 else value
        return self.frmt.format(value)
    def maxValue(self):
        return self._maxValue
    def minValue(self):
        return self._minValue
    def magnitude(self):
        return int(floor(log10(self.size()-1) + 1))
    def getRange(self):
        return 'Range[{:d}, {:d}]'.format(\
            self.minValue(), self.maxValue())
    def disp(self, binary=False):
        type = 's' if binary else 'd'
        frmt = '{:0' + str(self.magnitude()) + 'd}. {:' + type + '}'
        i = 0 
        for item in self.tolist():
            value = self.intToBin(item) if binary else item
            print(frmt.format(i, value))
            i+=1
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{:s}[{:d}]'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.size())

class ByteArray(TypedIntegerArray):
    def __new__(self, size):
        return TypedIntegerArray.__new__(self, 'b', size)
class UByteArray(TypedIntegerArray):
    def __new__(self, size):
        return TypedIntegerArray.__new__(self, 'B', size)
class IntegerArray(TypedIntegerArray):
    def __new__(self, size):
        return TypedIntegerArray.__new__(self, 'h', size)
class UIntegerArray(TypedIntegerArray):
    def __new__(self, size):
        return TypedIntegerArray.__new__(self, 'H', size)
class LongArray(TypedIntegerArray):
    def __new__(self, size):
        return TypedIntegerArray.__new__(self, 'l', size)
class ULongArray(TypedIntegerArray):
    def __new__(self, size):
        return TypedIntegerArray.__new__(self, 'L', size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create 1 of each type of array
    byteArr = ByteArray(8)
    ubyteArr = UByteArray(8)
    intArr = IntegerArray(16)
    uintArr = UIntegerArray(16)
    longArr = LongArray(32)
    ulongArr = ULongArray(32)

    # Specify a format for the ranges
    frmt = '{:17s} {:s}'

    # Print each of the ranges
    print frmt.format(byteArr, byteArr.getRange())
    print frmt.format(ubyteArr, ubyteArr.getRange())
    print frmt.format(intArr, intArr.getRange())
    print frmt.format(uintArr, uintArr.getRange())
    print frmt.format(longArr, longArr.getRange())
    print frmt.format(ulongArr, ulongArr.getRange())

    # Test array mutation and display
    for i in range(byteArr.size()):
        byteArr[i] = byteArr.maxValue() if i % 2 == 0 else byteArr.minValue()
    byteArr.disp(True)
```

**Output**

```
ByteArray[8]      Range[-128, 127]
UByteArray[8]     Range[0, 255]
IntegerArray[16]  Range[-32768, 32767]
UIntegerArray[16] Range[0, 65535]
LongArray[32]     Range[-2147483648, 2147483647]
ULongArray[32]    Range[0, 4294967295]
0. 01111111
1. 10000000
2. 01111111
3. 10000000
4. 01111111
5. 10000000
6. 01111111
7. 10000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are actually trying to do is to customize the creation of your typed array classes. Things like `numBits` or `maxValue` are properties of the type, not of a single instance, and should therefore be class attributes. Actually, in your current implementation, they are class attributes: they are set in the `__new__` method whenever an instance is created. Remember that the first parameter to `__new__` is actually the class, not an instance. It's often called `cls` instead of `self` to make that clear.

Customization of class creation is typically done using metaclasses. The `__new__` method of the metaclass is called to create the actual class. All the class attributes of the new class can be set here:

```
from array import array

class TypedArrayMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):
        if "typecode" in dct:
            typecode = dct["typecode"]
            dct["num_bits"] = 8 * array(typecode).itemsize
            dct["is_signed"] = typecode.islower()
            # any other class attributes go into dct
        return type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)

class TypedArray(array):
    __metaclass__ = TypedArrayMeta
    # other methods go here
```

You can then easily define all the custom typed array classes:

```
class ByteArray(TypedArray): typecode = "b" 
class UByteArray(TypedArray): typecode = "B" 
class IntegerArray(TypedArray): typecode = "h"
class UIntegerArray(TypedArray): typecode = "H"
class LongArray(TypedArray): typecode = "l"
class ULongArray(TypedArray): typecode = "L"
```

The class attributes are now set properly even before an instance is created:

```
print(ByteArray.num_bits, ByteArray.is_signed)
print(UByteArray.num_bits, UByteArray.is_signed)
print(IntegerArray.num_bits, IntegerArray.is_signed)
print(UIntegerArray.num_bits, UIntegerArray.is_signed)
print(LongArray.num_bits, LongArray.is_signed)
print(ULongArray.num_bits, ULongArray.is_signed)
```

As to your first question, on my 64-bit Linux, the "L" type is actually 8 bytes.